# As simple or as simply as possible: should an adjective or adverb be used?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

For the following sentence:

The rockets were modelled as simply/simple as possible.

I'm confused which of the two options is best. It feels like both options are potentially valid: the modelling is simple (pick adverb), or the rocket model is simple (adjective). Adding 'to be' forces:

The rockets were modelled to be as simple as possible.

Is there a preferred answer when omitting 'to be', or are both options defensible?

Comment: "Modeled as simply" and "modeled to be as simple" are two different forms. So, *to be* is not omitted from the first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree that with the adverb, the ambiguity does exist. But I think that the adverbial usage slants towards the 'simplest possible modelling process' rather than 'aiming for the simplest possible final  model'. Adverbs are usually happiest modifying the verb.

But you *can't* use the adjective in your first example – the sentence would be ungrammatical; a flat adverb *is* sometimes available to help, but not 'simple'. And you can't use a resultative construction: 'We made the models simple' works, but 'We modelled the rockets simple' doesn't.

You have to be more wordy to disambiguate clearly, as you imply. Possibilities are:

- *The rockets were modelled using the simplest modelling process possible.*

or

- *The rockets were modelled so as to produce the simplest models possible.*

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence, "The rockets were modeled as simply as possible", we use "simply" since it is part of an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "modeled".

In the sentence, "The rockets were modeled to be as simple as possible", "simple" is no longer in the position of an adverb but rather an adjective because of the verb "to be".

Answer (score 0):

"Simple" is an adjective and refers to the attribute of a noun.
"As simple as possible" means that the "understandability" or "complexity" of text should be very simple (easy to understand).

"Simply" is an adverb and refers to how to do something, the manner of doing something.  "As simply as possible" means the manner in which you explain something. We want to explain something (that is not simple) as simply as possible (in a manner that is easy to understand, that simplifies one's ability to understand something that is not simple in complexity).